# How to change background of bootstrap accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap accordion and want to change the accordion-heading background on click, and it works fine when you have to click to close a accordion-group, but when the accordion-group close automatically when you click another it fails. I'm checking for the "in" class that change automatically.

```
$( ".accordion-group div" ).click(function() {
  if ($(".accordion-group div").hasClass( "in" )) {
    $(this).css("width","110%");
  } else {
    $(this).css("width","80%")
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bg250Lhe/

Comment: No need for script, why not just do this with css rules?

Comment: I need to change the accordion-heading not the body of the accordion, and the heading don't have a class, and if i use toggle i will still have the same problem when i click on a different accordion-group.

Comment: well that's not what you posted. Please make sure questions address actual issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat ugly, but it works. You can probably find out what gets passed to the methods and simplify selectors with that.

```
$('#accordion2').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('.accordion-heading a').removeClass('bigger');
    $(this).find('.accordion-body.in').prev('.accordion-heading')
      .find('a').addClass('bigger');
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bg250Lhe/5)**

Comment: I need to change the accordion-heading, not the accordion-body